# Prove the area of a trapezoid is greater than the definite integral in convex function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I want to prove the area of a trapezoid is greater than the definite integral in convex function using only the definition of a convex function not using the geometry.
In other words,
$$ \frac{1}{{b-a}}\int_a^bf(x)dx \le \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is convex, then
$$f((1-t)a+tb)\le (1-t)f(a)+tf(b)$$
for $0\le t\le 1$. Therefore
$$\int_0^1 f((1-t)a+tb)\, dt\le \int_0^1\left((1-t)f(a)+tf(b)\right)\,dt.$$

Comment: OMG. It's too simple.